# Generator expressions and brackets

Tags: python, python-2.7

why are brackets, specifically parentheses, necessary for generator expressions which contain tuples?

Why

```
((x, y)
 for x in range(10)
 for y in range(20))
```

instead of

```
(x, y
 for x in range(10)
 for y in range(20))

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The latter is kind of ambiguous; starts like a normal tuple, but then turns out to be a generator later in the parse. (Not just for generators, also in list comprehensions)

Comment: yes :) ill accept that answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter is kind of ambiguous: It starts like a normal tuple, but then turns out to be a generator later in the parse. Maybe this becomes more apparent if we have more than two elements, as in `(1, 2, 3, 4, x for x in range(10))`.

This can also be seen in the [grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html):

```
generator_expression ::=  "(" expression comp_for ")"
```

Where `expression` later boils down to `atom` (among others)

```
atom      ::=  identifier | literal | enclosure
enclosure ::=  parenth_form | list_display
               | generator_expression | dict_display | set_display
               | string_conversion | yield_atom
parenth_form ::=  "(" [expression_list] ")"
expression_list ::=  expression ( "," expression )* [","]
```

I.e., an `expression_list` like `x, y` has to be enclosed in parentheses (except in an assignment, like `a = b, c`, where it can be used directly).

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
```

(Not just for generators, also for list comprehensions, and also in Python 3.)

Comment: 1 for looking up the spec, but is it really ambiguous? not once you examine the entire expression?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It's obvious by *inspection*, but parsers don't inspect per se, they read the input token by token and look for a pattern match in the grammar.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I take your point, but the `for` and `in` keywords should be easy enough to detect via a parser? I often accidentally write things like `[a, int(b) for a, b in zip(lst1,lst2)]`, could Python be different?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The 1, 2 can also be used in a return statement or in a for loop I.e. return 1, 2 and for age, name in persons:

Comment: @Chris_Rands: The thing is that once the parser does detect those it then has to backtrack through the tokens to reparse the input. This makes the parser both slower and more complex.

Comment: I guess one ambiguity arises from the fact that it is difficult to tell apart the "list-display" vs the generator as they share the same initial syntax. [1,2,3,4] vs [1,2,3,4 for x in range(10)], although arguably you could do a bit more work and expect a "for" token for it to be a generator and if no for is present its a list-display, hence the backtrack that Ignacio has mentioned.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I also get caught out by writing the comprehension in that way, often as well.